# ScrollToRowAtIndexPath is taking too much time

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to scroll the table to display the last cell. I am using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` bottom method, but it is taking too much time. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` might be taking too long, what are you doing in it?

Comment: Are you doing it in main queue ?

Comment: Run your app with profiler and see what takes too much time, then fix that.

Comment: @JonSnow can you call scrollToRowAtIndexPath off the main thread? :)

Comment: Show some code. what exactly are you doing?

Comment: yes I am doing it on main thread

Comment: scrollToRowAtIndexPath can not be call on other thread.

Answer (score 0):

To animate with a custom time, you can use this code:

```
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
var offset = tableView.contentSize.height

let offsetPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
    tableView.setContentOffset(offsetPoint, animated:false)
})
```

Then you can replace 0.1 with the number of seconds you want to animate the scroll with.

EDIT:

If you don't want any animation you can also try:

```
let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections() - 1
let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1

tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: lastSectionIndex), at: .top, animated: false)
```

Comment: What if rows have different heights?

Comment: ok. have edited answer, assuming you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: This looks like a slow reimplementation of `UITableView.rectForRow(at:)`.

Comment: ok. i think the rough idea is to get the height of the table view - i hope this edit fixes the speed issue.

Comment: Your edits are better for this specific case, but forcing the layout is probably unnecessary. I'd probably use `rect(forSection)` instead so the table view can decide what does and doesn't need layout. (But I suspect this isn't really the OP's problem; might be wrong, but I'm guessing it's something else.)